# Django: How to iterate over form fields choices without knowing the fields name?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form whose fields are created in its __init__method:

```
class Form(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, modelInstance, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # create fields based of modelInstance data (because it might change)
        self.fields[modelInstance.name] = models.ChoiceField(choices=SomeChoices, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Therefore i can not know in advance how the field may be named.

#### Now how can I iterate over the field choices without knowing its name?

*What I'd like:*

```
{% for field in form %}
    <p>sometext</p>
      {% for value, text in field.NAME.choices %}
          <input type="radio" name="{{ field.name }}" value="{{value}}" id="id_{{ field.name }}_{{forloop.counter0}}">
          <label>{{text}}</label>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I know field.NAME only returns the actual field name and does not give me access to its choices. But how else can I do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check this [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect)

Comment: I am already using RadioSelect as a widget on my form. Documentation iterates over the radio choices like I want to, yes, but only because they explicitly specify the fields name ('beatles'). Customizing the template might work, but I don't want to edit global templates for this one usecase.